# Difference between an it block and a specify block in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What is the difference between an it block and a specify block in RSpec?

```
subject { MovieList.add_new(10) }

specify { subject.should have(10).items }
it { subject.track_number.should == 10}
```

They seem to do the same job. Just checking to be sure.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The methods are [the same](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/80bdf067758678ee32191c04f4d479031e20606d/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L53-L67); they are provided to make specs read in English nicer based on the body of your test. Consider these two:

```
describe Array do
  describe "with 3 items" do
    before { @arr = [1, 2, 3] }

    specify { @arr.should_not be_empty }
    specify { @arr.count.should eq(3) }
  end
end

describe Array do
  describe "with 3 items" do
    subject { [1, 2, 3] }

    it { should_not be_empty }
    its(:count) { should eq(3) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You're correct, Brandon, `it` and `specify` are identical methods. You can see where they're defined [here in the source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L53-67).

Comment: Excellent catch! Amazing what you can find from reading the source. :) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Here is a gist with the examples methods names as of december 2013: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/7893586 (example, it, specify, focus, ...)

Comment: [better rspec](http://betterspecs.org/) advise against the use of `should`, and in favor of `expect`

Comment: UPDATE to the excellent link from @Jordan:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L101-194 is now the spot where to find it.

Comment: Just a heads up that `its(:count)` is no longer part of rspec core, see https://github.com/rspec/rspec-its and https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509

Comment: guys, please use canonical links for github files, it's just only one keystroke: "y"