# TDD with Capybara (Rails); difference between page.should and expect(page).to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, capybara

I'm new to the world of rails and test driven development. For TDD, I'm using RSpec and Capybara.
Currently, I'm working on a tutorial to learn more about Rails and the author is using following syntaxes:

```
page.should have_title('All users')
expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
```

Since it seems that both are interchangeable I'm wondering when to use which syntax? Because, for the described case above, I could also write:

```
page.should have_title('All users')
page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
```

Which basically does the same, right?

Also, when should I use "specify" instead of "it"?

```
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
specify { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }
```

In this case, I could also write:

```
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
it { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }
```

I guess the decision of which one to use is based on what I want to express. Maybe, you can help me out here?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
page.should have_title('All users')
expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
```

**Go with the latter one**, it's newer, they're pushing in that direction. I don't know if they have the intent of deprecating the former, but if they do, you won't have to go update all your code.

```
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
specify { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }
```

They are aliases, so just **choose the one that makes it clearer**. If you name your tests, you will know when to use which ([example](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing/blob/92d42ce35c5fe187481a6d43d401089db20129b6/spec/seeing_is_believing_spec.rb#L249-260)).

```
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
```

Frankly, I **avoid the non-named spec style**. It's a bit too magical, making it difficult to reason about, and often requiring acrobatic setup to get the subject to work out correctly. Also, I run my specs with `--format documentation`, and the auto-generated message is never what I want. In this case, I'd want to say something like `it 'has a signout link'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I just have get used to the whole tdd thing and also to the syntax in order to get a feeling when which alias to use. btw: the "--format documentation" is pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

the expect syntax is the new syntax, its also the one that is recommended by the rspec team, see: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax

Regarding it and specify, see: [Difference between an it block and a specify block in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484133/difference-between-an-it-block-and-a-specify-block-in-rspec)

Comment: The blog link is invaluable. It also helps in explaining how we can disable the use of should altogether on new projects. Good one!

Answer (score 0):

When you have the same subjects for multiple lines, you could DRY it up using `subject` and `should`. Using `expect` can actually make your code less DRY.
See: http://betterspecs.org/#subject

You gave this example:

```
page.should have_title('All users') 
page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
```

It's better to say:

```
subject { page }
it { 
  should have_title('All users')
  should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
}
```

This is interesting because in the betterspecs link above, the preferred way is not to use `expect`, but to use `should` in favor of DRY. You can see myronmarston's comment about this here: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax#comment-564045016