# What does the 'specify' method do in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm working through chapter 6 of Michael Hartl's tutorial and I came across this code

```
describe "with invalid password" do
  let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

  it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
  specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
```

What does the last line do?  Specifically, what does specify do?  I couldn't find anything on it through google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`specify` is simply the alias of `it`. You can check [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/80bdf067758678ee32191c04f4d479031e20606d/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L53-67)

you can check more here [Difference between an it block and a specify block in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484133/difference-between-an-it-block-and-a-specify-block-in-rspec)

The last line just check it is `false` or not if it you supply invalid password.

Comment: yea :) btw, i doubt that OP will accept any answer. New user usually don't.

Answer (score 0):

`specify` is the same as `it` - some people think it reads better.

For a detailed example that shows the different context you may choose to use it, have a look at this example [Difference between an it block and a specify block in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484133/difference-between-an-it-block-and-a-specify-block-in-rspec)